# corba implementations where are they found

Tags: java, corba

Corba is a specification and is rmi a corba implementation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, RMI has nothing to do with CORBA, they two are completely different.  However, RMI *can* be configured to use the CORBA IIOP wire protocol, if required, but this is legacy stuff.

The Sun JRE ships with a CORBA implementation, accessed via the `org.omg` package.

Comment: org OH MY GOD yes please avoid CORBA

Comment: well as i understood from this post that corba is not used today. Then what specification do people use instead of corba ?

Comment: @user581544: CORBA is used in plenty of places - there's a lot of legacy mainframe systems out there. For new development, though, it's deader then A-line flares with pockets in the knees.  What purpose do you want to use it for?

Comment: An overview of CORBA implementations has been posted in the resources section of ORBzone.org, see http://www.orbzone.org